# From dateFromString to stringFromDate

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a date in String that arrives in the following format:

```
"2015-11-15 14:16:15 +0000"
```

and I want to display it in a localised format and even calculate the age.
To get to NSDate I use this code:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss +SSSS"
let birthDate = self.dateFormatter.dateFromString(userProfile["birthdate"] as! String)
```

Then to display the date (in a short format) I change the dateFormatter

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let birthDateShort = self.dateFormatter.stringFromDate(birthDate!)
```

I could of course just pull out the text from the initial string if I didn't need the NSDate format for other reasons.  But it still seems like a long roundtrip , is this the "correct" method?

Comment: I think there's no "shorter way" to do this. Small correction: if you want 24h date format you should use "HH:mm..." format instead of "hh:mm..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *exactly* the right thing to do. And it's not a "long roundtrip". A string is just a string: just a representation, a bunch of letters / glyphs for a human being to read. A *date* is serious calendar-related piece of information. You need that date as a central pivot point for doing anything calendrically meaningful. And that's exactly what you're doing. NSDateFormatter is provided exactly so you can do the very kind of thing you *are* doing.

Comment: Thanks Matt, always grateful for your help !